# When is it okay to log filename/line information for errors?

Tags: c++, debugging, logging

We have a closed-source commercial C++ application. Some of our logged error messages are in plain English like "ERROR: could not read file 'foo'". While others use a macro to print filename/line information like ""SplineReticulator.cpp(423): out of bounds". This is not an assert or a crash, the application recovers fine, but it's an error we want to log.

What is a good rule of thumb when plain-English error message is appropriate vs. a filename/line one? Or are filename/line type errors even appropriate for closed-source commercial software? We've heard the argument they are unprofessional looking, but they are handy for debugging.

Comment: If you don't want to disclose file/line information, you can replace it by a [GUID](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier). File/line information is just a grep away and users can clearly identify these logs as debug data for maintainers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your application produces a log file, then put all your module name/line number stuff in there. The errors for the user should be in plain $usersLocalLanguage whenever possible. If you need the detailed info while trouble-shooting a client's problem, you can get the user to email the log file to you, and dissect that all you want.

If you *don't* have a log file, then you might want to have a dialogue box that has a simple error for the user, and then a "details" panel (closed, by default) where they can copy the tech details (with filename/line number) and paste into an email and send it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Our guideline is that technical details are only logged at debug level. All other messages are for customer consumption and must be worded appropriately with a minimum of technical jargon.(mere humans must be able to understand. :-)